# Cloud Functions v1, wildcards not working in functions.firestore.onCreate, empty context.params

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I updated Firebase Cloud Functions to v1.0.1 and decided to give it a go using the new Unit Testing features.

There is one issue for which I could not find a solution:

```
exports.updateBestTime = functions.firestore
   .document("users/{userId}/exercises/{exercise}/times/{timeId}")
   .onCreate((snap, context) => {

       console.log(context) 

       ...
```

When this function gets called, `snap` is correct, `snap.ref` point to the document I passed. `context.params` which should contain the wildcards value for `userId`, `exercise` and `timeId`, is empty. 
This is the output from `console.log(context)`:

```
   { service: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
     name: 'projects/focos-debug/databases/(default)/documents/users/userId5/exercises/exercise4/times/timeId6' },
     eventType: 'providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create',
     timestamp: '2018-04-07T09:17:42.500Z',
     params: {} }
```

I don't have much experience with JavaScript so it's probably my fault. Could you help me?

Here's the code I use for testing:

```
const handstandTimePath = 'users/OLlJ3NFcgYXqS8T5vetYVKjzFbo1/exercises/handstand/times/test';

const snap = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(
    {time: 30},
    handstandTimePath
);

// Call the wrapped function with the constructed snapshot.
const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.updateBestTime);
return wrapped(snap).then(function() {
    return firestore.doc(handstandTimePath).get();
}).then(function(createdSnap) {
    assert.property(createdSnap.data(), 'dateAndTime');
    assert.property(createdSnap.data(), 'time');
    assert.include(createdSnap.data(), {time: 30});
})
```

Comment: It seems the wildcard usage correct and should return the path values when onCreate triggered. I think this version's bugs, and will be corrected soon. Or pull a request for firebase cloude functions https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pulls here the full information about wildcard usage link for more detail: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to pass `params` as additional parameters to the wrapped function.

For instance:

```
let data = test.database.makeDataSnapshot({
    valProp1: "hello",
    valProp2: 12345
}, "my/path/param1/param2");

await test.wrap(myFunctions.func1)(data,
    {
        params: {
            param1: userId,
            param2: orderId
        }
    });
```

As seen in this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues/10).